# extract xml data/content from a url using shell scripting

Tags: unix

I need the xml content to be downloaded in file.xml from a url .say for example this is the url http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=26  I want to extract the xml content of it as follows to a file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss version="0.91">
<channel>
<title>PistonHeads (Motoring News)</title>
<link>http://www.pistonheads.com/news/</link>
<description>Motoring News</description>

<item>
<title>Bowler Nemesis Joins Spyker At CPP</title>
<description>Plans confired for Nemesis EXR road car to be built in Coventry</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I tried wget "url" -o file.xml ... and when I open file.xml... it is just returning

> http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=26
>   => `news091.asp?c=26' Resolving www.pistonheads.co.uk... done. Connecting to www.pistonheads.co.ukhttp://xx.xxx.xxx.xx connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 5,016 text/xml
>
> 0K .... 100% 445.31 KB/s
>
> 13:37:13 (445.31 KB/s) - `news091.asp?c=26' saved 5016/5016

Is there any other way to solve this..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this as the output:

```
PistonHeads (Motoring News) http://www.pistonheads.com/news/ Motoring News
```

Then this will do the trick:

```
wget -q -O - http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=26 \
  | egrep '(title>|link>|description>)' | head -3 \
  | sed -e 's/.*>\([^>]*\)<.*/\1/' | tr '\n' ' '
```

If however you just want the output of the link written to a file, use this:

```
wget -O file.xml http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=2
```

Note the capital O for the option to write the file.

Comment: wen i run the script along with the command mentioned above it says                                                               grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g

Comment: Looks like your system doesn't support `grep -E`. You could try replacing it with `egrep` (remove the `-E` too).

Comment: now the grep error is not coming but it says                        
Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g                   
 I tried removing the last sed part of the given command.It didnt show error.I gave like 
wget -q -O - http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=26 \
  | egrep '(title>|link>|description>)' | head -3 \
  | sed -e 's/.*>\([^>]*\)<.*/\1/' file.xml            .        When i opened the file.xml it shows same  the result as before (wen i used wget "url" -o file.xml)

Comment: You could use `| tr '\n' ' '` at the end, it just converts the new lines into spaces. If you want it to write to file.xml you'll have to add `> file.xml` to the end. I'll update the answer with these changes.

Comment: Thanks.now i m not getting any errors but file.xml contains PistonHeads (Motoring News) http://www.pistonheads.com/news/ Motoring News .... (which is the value of title,link, descp) is it possible to get the output of file.xml as follows        
<channel>
<title>PistonHeads (Motoring News)</title>
<link>http://www.pistonheads.com/news/</link>
<description>Motoring News</description>
<item>
 <title>Revealed: BMW 6 Series Coupe</title>
 <link>http://www.pistonheads.com/news/default.asp?storyId=23326 </link>
<description>New BMW coupe will arrive summer</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>

Comment: I think perhaps I misread what you want and gave you a more complicated answer. If you just want to content of that link written to a file it's simply: `wget -q -O file.xml http://www.pistonheads.co.uk/xml/news091.asp?c=26`